# Confused by Perl lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: regex, perl

I am confused by Perl lookahead `(?=regex)` and lookbehind `(?<=regex)` and need some help to understand it.

Does lookahead mean `look to the right of (?=regex)`

Does lookbehind mean `look to the left of (?<=regex)`

I also noticed that lookbehind (?<=regex) only works with fixed width regex, I use a simple example to ask next question.

For example, give following lines of code, I want to match numbers but only if it is not in a comment line. So it should match `2`, not `1`

```
 #Comment 1
 my $number = 2
```

I tried following

```
/(?<!^#)\d/ 
match a number if the line does not start with #
```

That did not work, is that because it is not a fixed width lookbehind regex ?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you trying to parse?

Comment: I am just teaching myself some Perl regex, use that code for example only.

Comment: I understand but without context and rules, your question doesn't have any sense.

Comment: mmm, I believe my question is very specific and clear.

Comment: "mmmmmm" : "For example, give following lines of code,". What kind of code ?

Comment: it does not matter, I want to match number in that code, not to run that code, and someone just abused his vote down. Also tell me which other language use my to define variables.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I really doesn't matter what this language may be, and your rudeness is unwelcome. Pretend he said it was a text file.

Comment: @AskandLearn: You need to specify whether your comment indicator can appear in the middle of the line. From your attempt at writing a regex it appears not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct, lookahead and lookbehinds search from the place they are inside the regex.  So your example `/(?<!^#)\d/` will match any digit as long as it's not **immediately** following a `#` at the start of a string.

For example:

```
my $string = "123 #456 #789"
while ($string =~ /(?<!#)(\d+)/g) {
     print $1;
}
```

The above will print `1235689`.  Only the 4 and 7 will be skipped because they are immediately preceded by a `#`

**Update**

To talk about your specific regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "#123 #456 #789";
while ($string =~ /(?<!^#)(\d+)/g) {
     print $1;
}
```

The above will print `23456789`, because only the number `1` is preceded by a `#` that is at the start of a string.

Comment: I still think (?<^#) is a fixed width lookbehind, could you explain it a little bit more ?

Comment: I think I got it, `^` means beginning of the string not beginning of line in lookbehind.

Comment: @AskandLearn: That *is* a fixed-length look-behind. What is puzzling you? The `^` behaves the same inside and outside a look-behind. It matches the beginning of the string, and also the point immediately after a newline if the `/m` modifier is in effect

Comment: @Borodin Thanks very much for the replay, I just thought `^` still matches all the way back to start of the line. Just trying to see if I can use lookbehind to exclude all the comments lines. Will that work ?